# How to convert url's into links and images in a contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When a user enters the URL of any image into the contenteditable div, the code below will automatically convert it into an image (through the `img` tag on the contenteditable div).

The problem with this is that it converts any URL that the user enters into an image tag.

`http://example.com` would be converted to `http://example.com

Is there a way to convert ordinary links into links (through the `<a>` tag) and image URL's inside image tags?

```
<script>

var saveSelection, restoreSelection;

if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
    saveSelection = function(containerEl) {
        var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        var preSelectionRange = range.cloneRange();
        preSelectionRange.selectNodeContents(containerEl);
        preSelectionRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
        var start = preSelectionRange.toString().length;

        return {
            start: start,
            end: start + range.toString().length
        }
    };

    restoreSelection = function(containerEl, savedSel) {
        var charIndex = 0, range = document.createRange();
        range.setStart(containerEl, 0);
        range.collapse(true);
        var nodeStack = [containerEl], node, foundStart = false, stop = false;

        while (!stop && (node = nodeStack.pop())) {
            if (node.nodeType == 3) {
                var nextCharIndex = charIndex + node.length;
                if (!foundStart && savedSel.start >= charIndex && savedSel.start <= nextCharIndex) {
                    range.setStart(node, savedSel.start - charIndex);
                    foundStart = true;
                }
                if (foundStart && savedSel.end >= charIndex && savedSel.end <= nextCharIndex) {
                    range.setEnd(node, savedSel.end - charIndex);
                    stop = true;
                }
                charIndex = nextCharIndex;
            } else {
                var i = node.childNodes.length;
                while (i--) {
                    nodeStack.push(node.childNodes[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    }
} else if (document.selection) {
    saveSelection = function(containerEl) {
        var selectedTextRange = document.selection.createRange();
        var preSelectionTextRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        preSelectionTextRange.moveToElementText(containerEl);
        preSelectionTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", selectedTextRange);
        var start = preSelectionTextRange.text.length;

        return {
            start: start,
            end: start + selectedTextRange.text.length
        }
    };

    restoreSelection = function(containerEl, savedSel) {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(containerEl);
        textRange.collapse(true);
        textRange.moveEnd("character", savedSel.end);
        textRange.moveStart("character", savedSel.start);
        textRange.select();
    };
}

function createLink(matchedTextNode) {
    var el = document.createElement("img");
    el.src = matchedTextNode.data;
    el.appendChild(matchedTextNode);
    return el;
}

function shouldLinkifyContents(el) {
    return el.tagName != "A";
}

function surroundInElement(el, regex, surrounderCreateFunc, shouldSurroundFunc) {
    var child = el.lastChild;
    while (child) {
        if (child.nodeType == 1 && shouldSurroundFunc(el)) {
            surroundInElement(child, regex, createLink, shouldSurroundFunc);
        } else if (child.nodeType == 3) {
            surroundMatchingText(child, regex, surrounderCreateFunc);
        }
        child = child.previousSibling;
    }
}

function surroundMatchingText(textNode, regex, surrounderCreateFunc) {
    var parent = textNode.parentNode;
    var result, surroundingNode, matchedTextNode, matchLength, matchedText;
    while ( textNode && (result = regex.exec(textNode.data)) ) {
        matchedTextNode = textNode.splitText(result.index);
        matchedText = result[0];
        matchLength = matchedText.length;
        textNode = (matchedTextNode.length > matchLength) ?
            matchedTextNode.splitText(matchLength) : null;
        surroundingNode = surrounderCreateFunc(matchedTextNode.cloneNode(true));
        parent.insertBefore(surroundingNode, matchedTextNode);
        parent.removeChild(matchedTextNode);
    }
}

var textbox = document.getElementById("text");
var urlRegex = /http(s?):\/\/($|[^ ]+)/;

function updateLinks() {
    surroundInElement(textbox, urlRegex, createLink, shouldLinkifyContents);
}

var $textbox = $(textbox);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $textbox.focus();

    var keyTimer = null, keyDelay = 1000;

    $textbox.keyup(function() {
        if (keyTimer) {
            window.clearTimeout(keyTimer);
        }
        keyTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {

            updateLinks();
            keyTimer = null;
        }, keyDelay);
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: 1. Is valid URL? >>> 2. matches `/\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)$/i`? >>> is **image**  else **is anchor**. Additionally you could also `new Image()` and  test for `onerror`.

Comment: Also instead of `[^ ]` use `[^\s]` or simply `\S`

Comment: Still can't get it to work separately for a link and an image @RokoC.Buljan

Comment: You're trying to create an as-you-type script that replaces on the fly *any* URL string - respectively - with `<a href="isLinkURL">` and `<img src="isImageURL">` inside the contenteditable, right?

Comment: PS another thing you have in that script... place `var $textbox = $(textbox);` and other DOM elements variables **inside** the DOM ready. That's what it's used for: to make sure the element is read by the  parser.